# SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm new to Angular.I have some problems regarding the passing data between back-end and front-end.I have  a system which passes booking data to the back-end to be saved in the database.Here is my code,

bookings.ts file

```
export class Bookings{
    departure:number;
    arrival:string;
    departd:string;
    returnd:string;
    classtype:string;
    adults:number;
    children:number;
    infants:number;
}
```

booking.component.ts

```
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {

  booking:Bookings =new Bookings();
  
  message:Observable<Object>;

  constructor(private flightService:FlightService, private router: Router) { }

  

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  save() {
    this.flightService.search(this.booking).subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
    // this.flightService.search(this.booking)
     
    this.booking = new Bookings();
    this.bookingData();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.save();    
  }

  bookingData() {
    this.router.navigate(['/bookings']);
  }

}
```

flight.service.ts

```
export class FlightService {

  private baseUrl='http://localhost:8080/flight/destinations';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getDestinations(): Observable<Destination[]>{
    // return  this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
    return  this.http.get<Destination[]>(this.baseUrl);
  }

  search(booking: Object): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, booking);
  }
  
}
```

FlightData Controller class

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/flight")
public class FligthtDataController {

@Autowired
private FligthtDataServices flightDataServices;

    @GetMapping("/destinations")
    public List<Destinations> getdestinationData() {
        List<Destinations> ds=flightDataServices.getDestinations();
        return ds;
    }


    @PostMapping("/destinations")
    public String  serchBooking(@RequestBody Booking booking) {
    System.out.println("Departure:"+booking.getDeparture());
    System.out.println("Arrival:"+booking.getArrival());
    System.out.println("Depart Date:"+booking.getDepartd());
    System.out.println("Return Date:"+booking.getReturnd());
    System.out.println("Class:"+booking.getClasstype());
    System.out.println("Adults"+booking.getAdults());
    System.out.println("Children"+booking.getChildren());
    System.out.println("Infants"+booking.getInfants());

        return "Successfuly saved the data";
    }

}
```

The problem with me is when I return a String  from the back-end in the Post method  as shown above the data from the front-end comes to the post method as expected but it gives a error in the console as follows
[image: error shown on console]

But when I return a number as below it doesn't show any error the value also printed on the console

```
  @PostMapping("/destinations")
    public int  serchBooking(@RequestBody Booking booking) {
    System.out.println("Departure:"+booking.getDeparture());
    System.out.println("Arrival:"+booking.getArrival());
    System.out.println("Depart Date:"+booking.getDepartd());
    System.out.println("Return Date:"+booking.getReturnd());
    System.out.println("Class:"+booking.getClasstype());
    System.out.println("Adults"+booking.getAdults());
    System.out.println("Children"+booking.getChildren());
    System.out.println("Infants"+booking.getInfants());

        return 123;
    }
```

No error in console as shown below the number also printed.
[image: no error 123 also get printed]

please help me to understand this. and help me to resolve this issue.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is not valid JSON that can be ran through `JSON.parse`, but a number is.

You can see examples here:

```js
// valid, will return 123
console.log(JSON.parse(123));

// invalid, will error
try {
 console.log(JSON.parse("Sucessfully saved the data"));
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Error", e)
}
// proper JSON "object" from the server
console.log(JSON.parse(`{"message": "Sucessfully saved the data"}`));
```

You need to return a proper JSON string from your server, like the one in the example, then read the `message` property from that response.

Answer (score 0):

just to add to @cjd82187 answer... you don't **have to** return JSON. My API happens to return a `string`, in which case I've added the following to `options`:

```js
responseType: 'text'
```

This, however, resulted in another issue: `"type text is not assignable to type json"`. The solution to this is the following:

```js
responseType: 'text' as 'json'
```

an example:

```js
this.httpClient.post<any>(
    this.statusApiEndpoint,
    jobId,
    {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'text' as 'json'
    }).map(r => {
           console.log(r)
           return r;
          });
```